# Fastest way to loop through tif stack and extract pixel values

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, mask

I have a large tif stack of images +1500, and to for each image i have ~ 100 position in x,y from which i want to extract the value of a mask.
The dataframe could be visualized by the lists below:

```
x=[80.1,80.2,80.1,80.2,80,2,80.3]
y=[40.1,40.2,40.1,40.2,40.2,40.3]
frame = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

The following code seems to work, however it takes quite some time to run through. Anyone who could provide a faster solution:

```
blue = image_loader_video(blue_video) # video as numpy array

def df_extractor(row):
    a,b = row['x'],row['y']
    frame = int(row['frame'])
    array = blue[frame]

    nx,ny = blue_shape
    y,x = np.ogrid[-a:nx-a,-b:ny-b]
    mask = x*x + y*y <= lip_int_size  
    mask2 = x*x + y*y <= lip_int_size+9 # to make a "gab" between BG and roi

    BG_mask = (x*x + y*y <=lip_BG_size)
    BG_mask = BG_mask-mask2
    return (sum((array[mask]))),np.median(((array[BG_mask])))

final_df['signal_np'],final_df['np_bg'] = final_df.apply(df_extractor,axis= 1)
```

Comment: Could you provide [`mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Would be open to running the apply in parallel?  How many cores do you have on your system?

Comment: I have 4 cores on the current system